# Condifitonal extend type typescript

Tags: typescript

i have the following code:

```
type Data = "a"
type DataTwo<T extends Data> = T extends "a" ? "a_a" : never
const func = <T extends Data> (data: T): DataTwo<T> => {
  switch(data) {
    case "a":
    return "a_a"; //Type '"a_a"' is not assignable to type 'DataTwo<T>'
    default:
    return neverFn(data)
  }
}

const neverFn = (data: any): never => {
  throw new Error(data)
}

const b = func<"a">("a") //b's type is "a_a"
```

My question is how do I make typescript understand that T is sent as the correct type and it should match a case in the return type of the function?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBEc0FgBQpKwJwAqA7gPYA8xUEAHsBAHYAmAzoYgHwpQ32NWHDGigB+dHAD6mKAC4oTCADcIAJ1wBjckzbAoAMwCuTTb2q0Gzdpzg8AFCyILiASgXxEZKsR7IeAN64UFBspACWwJoAFo5ErlBBOCEhmnBs0CJywSlqEMBGakySMmgA3FAA9JXE4NAA5Bil9VDhHEzk+uls4QDmTHAARgA20MDkUPgNniQU1Fz1OSEsEAZwRsPA2cm5+YXFSqpqAGJMcYiuOQC+uDc4Wjp6iirqp7zncApwTCDuz0coQI5YDRNTkUjPCEAUTUYLUH0uODuD10+kGvGMpkoIi49hECWqg3qHCmrWE0kwQA)

Comment: You can't. Use a type assertion.

Comment: Why don't you just write `<T extends Data>(data: T): "a_a"` as your function's signature, since that return type is guaranteed by `T` extending `Data`?

Comment: @kaya3 This was just a simple example, imagine there are many cases and DataTwo is a much bigger type with multiple conditions.

Comment: Then it's a *too*-simple example because it doesn't accurately reflect the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and there's nothing currently better than a type assertion.  But you probably want to make the example complete enough so that you can't just trivially work around it without the conditional type.  Even two cases would probably be enough.